# How can I obtain the Inno Setup version number from a batch or Inno Setup script?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to obtain the Inno Setup version number for use in an Inno Setup installer?

I cannot find a documented switch to return its version number (e.g. 5.5.6) and there doesn't seem to be an exposed predefined version constant exposed to Inno Setup scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the contrary @magicnumber, there is indeed a compiler version constant available directly in your inno-script. The predefined Preprocessor variable `Ver` returns the 32-bit encoded version of Inno Setup compiler. Highest byte holds the major version, lowest byte usually holds zero. Make it prettyful with the `DecodeVer` function. Example:

`#define MyCompilerVerStr DecodeVer(Ver)`

**Update:**

You can also add details if the compiler is the unicode or non-unicode version:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define MyInnoVersion DecodeVer(Ver) + " (unicode)"
#else
  #define MyInnoVersion DecodeVer(Ver) + " (non-unicode)"
#endif
```